# Rate of Convergence for derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convergence-divergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of differntible functions $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
And suppose that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly with rate $\varphi$ to a function $f$. That is:
$$\sup_x||f_n(x) - f(x)|| \leq \varphi(n), \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\varphi(n) = 0.$$

Suppose further that $f_n'$ converges uniformly to $f'$. Is there anything which can be said about the rate of convergence for the derivatives?

Thanks.

Comment: No. Consider something like $f=0$, $f_n(x)=\phi(n)\sin(g_n(x))$...

Comment: Or even simply $f_n(x)=ϕ_n·\sin(g_n·x)$.